# why will multiprocess spawn multi threads in every process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using python [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), here is a simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import signal

def process(_id):
    time.sleep(2)
    return _id

def init_worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

def main():
    pool = Pool(1, init_worker)
    for res in pool.imap(process, range(1000)):
        print res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this runs ok, what confused me is that:

```
# ps -eLaf | grep test_multi
cuidehe   4119  4118  4119  2    4 11:06 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi.py
cuidehe   4119  4118  4121  0    4 11:06 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi.py
cuidehe   4119  4118  4122  0    4 11:06 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi.py
cuidehe   4119  4118  4123  0    4 11:06 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi.py
cuidehe   4120  4119  4120  0    1 11:06 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi.py
```

aw you can see, I just forked one process, its pid is `4120`, so I think the pid `4119` is the main process, but **why 4 threads?**

one thing to point out is that, **not always 4 threads**, for example:

```
pool = Pool(1, init_worker)
cursor = parse_db["jd_raw"].find({"isExpired": 0},
        {"jdJob.jobPosition": 1, "jdJob.jobDesc": 1, "jdFrom": 1}, no_cursor_timeout=True).\
                batch_size(15)

for res in pool.imap(process, cursor):
    pass
```

this time is 6 :

```
cuidehe   4522  2655  4522 21    6 11:28 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi_mongo.py
cuidehe   4522  2655  4525  0    6 11:28 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi_mongo.py
cuidehe   4522  2655  4527  0    6 11:28 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi_mongo.py
cuidehe   4522  2655  4528 54    6 11:28 pts/25   00:00:01 python test_multi_mongo.py
cuidehe   4522  2655  4529 46    6 11:28 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi_mongo.py
cuidehe   4522  2655  4530  0    6 11:28 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi_mongo.py
cuidehe   4526  4522  4526 28    1 11:28 pts/25   00:00:00 python test_multi_mongo.py
```

And also, not only `main process` will spawn child threads, **but also child process will spawn child threads**, so **why multiprocess still needs to spawn child threads?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module uses three separate threads to manage a `Pool` in the background while your main program can continue. See `multiprocessing/pool.py` in your Python installation.